# WSP Deployment success, but can't find where to Activate

Tags: wspbuilder, solution-package

In "Central Administration – System Settings – Manage Farm Solutions" I can see that my Solution has been deployed, to http://sp2010/. However when I go to there, and try to activate this feature through "Site Settings - Manage Site Features" or "Site Settings - Site Collection Features" I can't find it, it's not there in the list!

Here's the feature.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Feature  Id="118849a2-9e81-4046-9329-36ebfdff5b8b"
          Title="edu.yale.som.auth.admin"
          Description="Deployment for edu.yale.som.auth.admin"
          Version="14.0.0.0"
          Hidden="FALSE"
          Scope="Web"
          DefaultResourceFile="core"
          ReceiverAssembly="edu.yale.som.auth.admin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b821d30408baea0"
          ReceiverClass="edu.yale.som.auth.admin.Deploy"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="elements.xml"/>
    <ElementFile Location="FBAProcessSingleUser.webpart" />
    <ElementFile Location="FBAProcessAllUsers.webpart" />    
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

I've downloaded this project from http://eduyalesomauth.codeplex.com/

Any ideas how I can activate this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My WSP was not complete, when I opened it with winRAR I couldn't verify feature.xml and other necessary files. Apparently I had the wrong WSPBuilder installed. The package now shows up in the Site Collection Features-screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the STSADM.exe or powershell commands to activate the same.

for stsadm

stsadm -o activatefeature -name **FeatureFolderName** -url http://yourweb

for powerswhell
Enable-SPFeature **FeatureFolderName** -Url http://yourweb

Comment: thanks, however it didn't work for stsadm. Here's the error:
"Feature with Id '###' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope."
I tried -o installFeature but that throws an Exception from Deploy.cs

Comment: Can you tell me the exact exception you get while executing this:
stsadm -o installfeature -name FeatureFolderName